# Does SharePoint Online use the Taxonomy update scheduler?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, timer-jobs, taxonomy, term-store

I'm currently having issues searching for content in SharePoint Online based on Content Types (using a managed metadata site column). If I search for a specific document (which I know is using this content type) using the SharePoint Search Query Tool, it is not even showing the Content Type ID which is assigned to it.

I have found online information about the **Taxonomy update scheduler job** which runs and should be populating this list *[site collection url]/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx*. My lists are completely empty so i'm now wondering if this is part of my search problem.

Has anyone experienced using this scheduler job online? Does anyone else who uses Termstore Metadata see items in this list?

Comment: You should be able to search by content type in SPO.  How are you doing the search?  Also, I've checked on a site collection in my tenant, and the list is populated.